# Increase Performance in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

I have a question about picking. I found a really neat way to do picking by rendering a single display call with lights turned off and everything and unique colour for each object, then simply finding what colour pixel is under the mouse pointer. It works fine and from I understand that also been used by others in the past for object picking. I thought rendering a single frame in that way will not be noticeable, however it is noticeable. I have to say I am using JOGL bindings.

So I was wondering what factors affect the performance in this case? I read on Apples dev guide NOT to use glBegin and glEnd and instead use buffers. Is that right? Am I right to think that it is possible to render a single frame without anyone noticing the flicker?

Comment: `glBegin()` and friends are good to begin with because they're simple, but you should really use VBOs or vertex arrays for real world applications, hence the Apple recommendation. `glBegin()` etc are deprecated now anyway.

Comment: "So I was wondering what factors affect the performance in this case?" What makes you think this is a performance issue? The only way this would be visible is if you *showed* the image. Yes, you might have a framerate stutter, but that's rather different than what you seem to be talking about. So, stop showing the image to the user; only use it for picking.

Comment: @Nicol - Yeah I just thought about that, I should be able to render into a separate buffer and pick from that, that's what you mean right?

Comment: @Alex: No. Render to the default framebuffer all you want. Just don't *show it*, with whatever "swapbuffers" command that JOGL provides. Do a `glClear` and render what you actually want to display.

Comment: @Nicol: Oh it seems so simple now to simply clear the framebuffer and draw again. Thanks a lot.